# Cascade MdiChildren

Tags: vb.net, winforms, linq

I'm trying to do a Window cascade for loaded child windows. I can't use LayoutMdi() as it changes the child form size.

I can do so using the parent's MdiChildren

```
    Dim i As Integer
    For Each frm As Form In Me.MdiChildren
        frm.Location = New Point(i, i)
        frm.BringToFront()
        i += 30
    Next
```

But that order is due to the load order. I could sort by .Top of the open windows but I'd rather use Z order. How can I determine a form's Z order in a given parent?

Another pass at the same problem - trying to get a sorted 'list' (another data structure may be better?) or forms sorted by .Top:

```
    Dim childForms As New List(Of Form)
    For Each frm As Form In Me.MdiChildren
        childForms.Add(frm)
    Next
    Dim sortedChildForms As Form() =
        From entry In childForms
        Order By DirectCast(entry.Top, Integer)
        Ascending Select entry
```

I'm a total novice at Linq so I don't really know what I'm doing here. The DirectCast failed as not supported Int to Int). I tried using`order by entry.Top` but that failed with:

```
    System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
    Message=Unable to cast object of type 
     WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Windows.Forms.Form,
     System.Windows.Forms.Form]' 
     to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form[]'.
```

So sort of two questions: Can I get the ZOrder of the MdiChild forms and how do I sort the resulting 'list' by either .Top or .Z ?

Please no C# only answers as they don't auto translate well to VB.Net in this context.

Comment: Use following code on button_click event: `Me.LayoutMdi(System.Windows.Forms.MdiLayout.Cascade)`

Comment: RE: Second sentence in OP - Cascade changes the displayed form size, which I do not want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires pinvoke, you must use the [GetWindow() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633515%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to enumerate the children in Z-order.  The basic scheme is the find the last MDI child window, the one on the bottom, and work your way up.  This code worked well:

```
Private Sub CascadeButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CascadeButton.Click
    Dim pos As Integer = 0
    If Me.MdiChildren.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    '' Find the child on the bottom
    Dim child = GetWindow(Me.MdiChildren(0).Handle, GW_HWNDLAST)
    Do While child <> IntPtr.Zero
        Form.FromHandle(child).Location = New Point(pos, pos)
        pos += 30
        '' Find the next on above it
        child = GetWindow(child, GW_HWNDPREV)
    Loop
End Sub

Private Const GW_HWNDLAST As Integer = 1
Private Const GW_HWNDPREV As Integer = 3
Private Declare Function GetWindow Lib "User32.dll" (hwnd As IntPtr, cmd As Integer) As IntPtr
```